# Bootstrap - Button gets 'pushed' out of jumbotron on small screen size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

When the browser height is reduced to that of a mobile screen, the button gets 'pushed' out of the jumbotron at the bottom. How can I prevent this?

```
    <div class="jumbotron g">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
            </div>

            <div id="jumbocontent" class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-
xs-12">
              <h1>This is the test text of the h1.</h1>
              <p>
The mate counts outside the area. A phenomenon seconds a baby 
characteristic next to the museum. A draining shelter scrolls the snail. A 
riding principal trashes the union. Into the obsessed sunlight suffers the 
sordid glow.</p>
              <button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-primary 
btn-lg">Order Our Service</button>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: I dont get this problem. What version of bootstrap are you using?
https://output.jsbin.com/biluvox

Comment: can you provide a working codepen or post your css here